# How to change page with JS in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want when the user successfully sign up it goes to the main page.
I already tried a lot of function but it doesn't work..

code :

```
var nama = document.getElementById("name");
var email = document.getElementById("email");
var userPw = document.getElementById("pass");
```

sign up code :

```
function store(){

var rePass = document.getElementById("re_pass");
if (userPw.value == rePass.value && nama.value != "") {
    alert("Berhasil daftar!");
} else {
    alert('Coba periksa lagi~');
    return;
}

localStorage.setItem('namaUser', nama.value);
localStorage.setItem('emailUser', email.value);
localStorage.setItem('passwordUser', userPw.value);
```

i tried this function also :

```
self.location = 'sign in.html';
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. make sure to clear the space between in this segment!!! **'sign in.html'**

```
window.location = 'sign in.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
window.location.replace("/");
```

or

```
window.location.href = "/";
```